# how to add service builder with liferay spring mvc plugin

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay-7

I have created plugin project (Spring MVC). But I can't configure this plugin project with service builder. When I am trying to build service, I am facing the below issue.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-
plugin:6.2.5:build-service (default-cli) on project Spring-demo: 
com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

View the below image:

[image]

[image]

How to solve this.

Comment: are you having trouble building the service jar?

Comment: I don't have problem to build service jar. I need to create service builder in spring MVC plugin. I have added new screenshot in my question.  I follow the below steps to create service builder.
   1. I create Plugin project "Spring MVC".
   2. Next I try to create the service builder for "Spring MVC".
   3. The popup doesn't show the plugin project in list.
How to solve this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

This look pretty much a Eclipse setup issue. Ideally, the dropdown should show up if you have a plugin project. I guess you have a setup errors that's blocking it from showing up in the wizard. Open the "Error Console" and see if there are any errors. Here are few things you can check:

- Do you have the right version of IDE installed? If you have installed via remote site, try downloading them from this URL https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20IDE/3.1.0%20B1/liferay-ide-updatesite-3.1.0-b1-201705141336.zip/download
- Do you have a proper Plugins SDK for Liferay setup?
- Do you have the build.properties inside the SDK with default properties for building the projects?
- Do you have at least one plugin project in your workspace?
- If you are starting fresh, other option you have is to download the eclipse bundle here https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20IDE/3.1.0%20B1/liferay-ide-eclipse-windows-x64-3.1.0-b1-201705141336.zip/download

Comment: Thank you for your response. There is no error in my eclipse console.
I have checked with following steps.
1. I have created Liferay MVC Plugin.
2. Then I create Liferay Portel. It shows in plugin list.
When I try to create service builder I face this issue.

Comment: If there are no error in "Error Log", make sure if you have a plugin project in your workspace. If  you have and its still not detecting, create a service.xml under /WEB-INF/ of your plugin project and try.  Make sure you installed the IDE from right eclipse update site.

Comment: I create Service.xml under WEB-INF/. Then I try to build service. it throws below error.

**No plugin found for prefix 'liferay' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Megala.P\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]**

Comment: In my Eclipse Error log it shows 
**!MESSAGE The POM for com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:jar:6.2.0 is missing, no dependency information available

!MESSAGE Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.0: Plugin com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:jar:6.2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository**

Comment: Try uninstalling the IDE plugin from eclipse and download from the site directly to your local. Then install using local archive option. Your exceptions tell me that you don't have the SDK setup.

Comment: Thank you YuVi, I will check and let you know.